# Jaxb2Marshaller in StaxEventItemReader causing UnmarshalException

Tags: jaxb, spring-batch, stax

So I'm trying to parse an xml and unmarshal it into a program. This is the example xml:

```xml
<MaintenanceTransaction:provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest
        xmlns:MaintenanceTransaction="http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransaction>
        <MaintenanceTransaction:eventInitiatedBy>
            <MaintenanceTransaction:identifier>FINACLE</MaintenanceTransaction:identifier>
        </MaintenanceTransaction:eventInitiatedBy>
        <MaintenanceTransaction:transactionDate>2014-06-21T19:00:32.356+01:00</MaintenanceTransaction:transactionDate>
        <MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransactionType>PRE-NOTIFICATION
        </MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransactionType>
        <MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceEntries>
            <MaintenanceTransaction:hasNewValues xsi:type="MaintenanceTransaction:DepositArrangement">
                <MaintenanceTransaction:enterpriseId xsi:type="MaintenanceTransaction:ArrangementIdentifier">
                    <MaintenanceTransaction:identifier>222000000322</MaintenanceTransaction:identifier>
                    <MaintenanceTransaction:enterpriseIdType>Term Deposit</MaintenanceTransaction:enterpriseIdType>
                </MaintenanceTransaction:enterpriseId>
                <MaintenanceTransaction:maturityDate>2014-10-08</MaintenanceTransaction:maturityDate>
            </MaintenanceTransaction:hasNewValues>
        </MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceEntries>
    </MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransaction>
</MaintenanceTransaction:provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest>
```

The xsd is defined as:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:MaintenanceTransaction="http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="./commonIFWxsd/IFWXML.xsd" />
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="./commonIFWxsd/Event.xsd" />
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="./commonIFWxsd/Arrangement.xsd" />
    <!-- end of TYPES REQUIRED FOR PARAMETERS -->
    <xsd:complexType name="provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="maintenanceTransaction" type="MaintenanceTransaction:MaintenanceTransaction" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- TYPES REQUIRED FOR PARAMETERS -->
    <xsd:element name="provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest" type="MaintenanceTransaction:provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest" />
</xsd:schema>
```

With the following setup of my StaxEventItemReader and Jaxb2Marshaller:

```xml
<bean id="uploadEventMessageReader" parent="abstractUploadEventMessageReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['fileToProcess']}"/>
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="maintenanceTransaction"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" scope="step">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt.MaintenanceTransaction</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem however is that I get the following exception.

```
 * [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02", local:"maintenanceTransaction"). Expected elements are (none)] on step uploadEventMessages, with message: uploadEventMessagesStep. 
 * --stacktrace:com.pwx.crs.frwk.exp.technical.CRS2UnexpectedBatchException: An unexpected exception occurred in batch job JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
```

Any idea what this is about?

When I slightly change the maintenanceTransaction opening tag of the input xml like this:

```xml
<MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransaction xsi:type="MaintenanceTransaction:MaintenanceTransaction">
```

It does work. But that is not a solution as the clients won't deliver the input xml's like that. So why is the error occuring? There seems to be a problem with determining which class maintenanceTransaction is part of.

Also tried different approaches on the marshaller bean definition:

```
<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" scope="step">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" scope="step">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt.ObjectFactory</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The results for both are the same and similar to the first error

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02", local:"maintenanceTransaction"). Expected elements are <{http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02}AccessTokenLifecycleStatus>
... and here the whole list of classes in the package.

But the xml is perfectly valid against the xsd, as that is done beforehand. Idea's, suggestions, ... that I could try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after researching through the code and debugging and much more labour I ended up with something that works. I don't exactly know why, as it was a guess, but it works.

```
<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt.MaintenanceTransaction</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappedClass" value="com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt.MaintenanceTransaction"/>
</bean>
```

As you can see it was not necessary to use the ObjectFactory as classesToBeBound (But it has to be noted that it would have worked as well but in my opinion this is more readable). The thing that really fixes it is adding a mappedClass.

From what I have seen in the code while debugging (I could not check the code f UnmarshallingImpl as this is part of rt.jar and this is not public even though it is part of the jre ...) The classesToBeBound parameter is used to create the jaxbContext for the unmarshaller and the mappedClass is passed to this unmarshaller as expectedType. But when this is not provided and the ObjectFactory is used as parameter the error clearly shows a list of expected classes and the one applicable is present ... Maybe a bug in the unmarshaller, maybe something that I don't understand. But my root problem is solved.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my theory.

What `mappedClass` actually does is switches the unmarshalling method from `unmarshaller.unmarshal(source)` to `unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, this.mappedClass)`. This is called "partial unmarshalling", i.e. you can unmarshal a known class from some element regardless of the element name.

So, as you say, this works for you. And it does not without `mappedClass`. This would mean that you are missing an element declaration for your root element. This also alignes well with the error you have reported:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
(uri:"http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02",
local:"maintenanceTransaction"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Which says basically the same thing.

This is also correct. As your schema does not declare a global element for the `maintenanceTransaction`, only for `provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest`.

So, basically you're unmarshalling the wrong element. And as your schema does not have a declaration for that, this fails. But if you specify exactly which type you want (thus providing the declaration "explicitly"), then it works.

Next, the question is, why do you you unmarshal the wrong element. My guess is that this is because you have

```
<property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="maintenanceTransaction"/>
```

This probably points the unmarshaller to use the `maintenanceTransaction` element as the root element. So the unmarshaller is applied to the wrong element.

Using `contextPath`, adding more bound classes etc. does not help as none of it adds the element declaration for the `maintenanceTransaction`.

Now, how to fix this. I see the following options:

- Add a global element for `maintenanceTransaction` to your schema
- (OR) Customize your schema to generate an additional `@XmlRootElement` for `MaintenanceTransaction`
- (OR) Don't use the `fragmentRootElementName`, unmarshal `provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest`
- (OR) Leave it as is with `mappedClass`

If you handle a specific case here, namely `maintenanceTransaction` then I'd use the  `fragmentRootElementName`/`mappedClass` combo. Just as you do now.

Comment: The reason why maintenanceTransaction is the fragmentRootElementName is because I don't need the wrapping class. I just need to parse the the maintenance transactions one by one, each maintenance transaction needs to be processed by the processor of spring batch. If I would take the provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest as fragmentRootElementName then I would be stuck with one big element that I need to process in one go. Not very optimal when I turn on the parallel processing as it will just be one atomic action. 1 read 1 process.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is (when I don't specify mappedClass) 'Expected elements are (none).' Wouldn't it have to be 'Expected elements are (uri:"http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02",
local:"provideCommunicationEvents_BatchRequest")'?

Comment: And another thing that I don't understand is that when I specify the ObjectFactory instead of MaintenanceTransaction as classesToBeBound, that the error says: Unexpected element (uri:"http://www.ing.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02", local:"maintenanceTransaction")  'Expected elements are ... ,<{http://www.ing.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02}MaintenanceTransaction>,...' Which is ... to me at least the same element except for the fact that mine is an instance and the expected one is the class.

Comment: @Juru Should be if you have it in your context. That would be if you use it as bound class explicitly or if you specify a context path which would include that `@XmlRootElement`-annotated class.

Comment: The wrapper class doesn't have an @XmlRootElement. It is clear to me that this is not alway generated, depends on how it is defined. So that would indeed explain why it is not in the list.

Comment: So that means that. 1. It use the mappedClass as expected element or 2 it uses all possible classes in the objectfactory as expected element or 3 it uses all elements with @XmlRootElement in the packages provided as expected elements. Its only weird that its not able to map an instance (unexpected) maintenanceTransaction to the expected MaintenanceTransaction.

Comment: @Juru It's a bit more complex tham that. There's also `@XmlRegistry` and `@XmlSeeAlso`. Feel free to ask another question on that, too large for a comment.

Comment: Ok, will do. Will reward you the bounty when I can (10h from now). Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem @lexicore, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `JAXBContext` on a model generated from an XML Schema you should do one of the following to get all the necessary metadata:

**Option #1 - Create it on the Generated `ObjectFactory` Class**

```xml
<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" scope="step">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt.ObjectFactory</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Option #2 - Create it on the Package Name(s) of the Generated Model**

```xml
<bean id="maintenanceTransactionUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" scope="step">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.pwx.crs.informationcollection.ifw.process.model.mt"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried the contextPath approach once but then I got a similar error: [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.pwx.com/Interface/CRS/MaintenanceTransaction_v02", local:"maintenanceTransaction"). Expected elements are <{http://www.pwx.co > here a list of all classes in the package.

Comment: Tried the ObjectFactory approach too, same result as for the contextPath.

Comment: @Juru - That's a better exception at least.  Are you able to update your question to include it?

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: When I specify the schema as well in the marshaller definition I get "Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'MaintenanceTransaction:maintenanceTransaction'."